# Ensure new form is created on the UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

I have multiple threads that write into a log form. Whatever thread has the first message will create the form on-the-fly. I use `MyForm.InvokeRequired` / `.Invoke(…)` for each form update, however the code sometimes deadlocks with the main thread in state *.WaitForWaitHandle*.

From what I understand -albeit might be totally off-, the issue is that sometimes a WorkerThread creates the form. Henceforth, `.InvokeRequired` will  always be true even if the form is subsequently updated from the UI thread. In the latter case, the UI thread might be waiting for itself?

I hope I can fix this by creating the form on the UI thread itself, but I don't know what control to start from while *MyForm==null*.

**Note**: There is a multi threaded API in the background with threads for receiving/sending/processing messages which I need to keep track of.

Simplified exampe:

```
public static LogForm MyForm;

public static void AddLogLine(string inText) // is called from multiple threads
{
    if (MyForm == null) MyForm = new LogForm();

    if (MyForm.InvokeRequired)
        MyForm.Invoke(new Action<LogForm, string>(_appendText), MyForm ,inText); // deadlock, UI thread state: .WaitForWaitHandle
    else
        _appendText(MyForm ,inText);
}
```

Comment: This is not even thread-safe, you could end up with 2 or more forms and lost data.

Comment: `MyForm.InvokeRequired` is meaningless and wrong.

Comment: Why are you using multiple threads in the first place? What problem are you solving?

Comment: @bommelding I always understood you don't have to synchronise calls to static methods, thus how could I end up with more than one form?

Comment: Because you have a static field. That is not automatically thread-safe.

Comment: And lay off the statics as much as possible. They are easy to start with and then they bite.

Comment: Create a class `Log`, add to it static method `Add` and static event `Added` (rise event when `Add` is called). That's your model and it now works, thread safe and beautiful. You can call `Log.Add` from anywhere in the software. ToDo: subscribe to this event somewhere to create a form (make form creation in existing UI thread if there is any, e.g. main form), subscribe to it in the form to append messages to the textbox/list.

Comment: @Sinatr - you still have to Invoke somewhere along that line. Because Added will be raised on the Thread that calls Add().

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you tu read about Synchornization Context:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I

Every form/dialog/usercontrol should be initialized on the UI thread, a fishy way to achieve this would be to create a public static reference of your main form:

```
public static Form1 StaticReference;
```

Set it on the constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
     StaticReference = this;
}
```

Then on your code elsewhere:

```
public static LogForm MyForm;
public static void AddLogLine(string inText) // is called from multiple threads
{
    <namespace>.StaticReference.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
      if (MyForm == null) 
         MyForm = new LogForm();

      Do whatever you want with MyForm within this block.
    });
}
```

Any solution you find you will still need to marshall the calls through the UI thread somehow.